# How to change default label of window?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, windows-server-2008, window

I want to change label name of windows program. The most general example is If I run command prompt the default label in taskbar is current cmd path. 
Second example when I run multiple instance of visual studio the default label name is the solution name.
Third example when I run word or excel, the default label is the name of document.
How to change name of label to own without changes inside programm?
How to change name of label inside running programm without program name changes?

Comment: This is rather vague. Can you please elaborate on your question?

Comment: ok, i edit my question

Comment: If you want to change the label of a command prompt window you can execute the command **title YourChosenNameGoesHere**

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to create a new shortcut to `cmd.exe`.

[image]

Click `Next`, then name it whatever you want the window name to be.

[image]

Click `Finish`.

Now when you run the shortcut, the window will be named what you saved the shortcut as.

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks it's easiest and general answer but good. I elaborate my question.